# Java hibernate Unable to commit against JDBC Connection

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jdbc

`I have created a Hibernate project named "animal" in which I utilize Hibernate Query Language (HQL) to establish a connection with a SQL Server database. Within the project, I've organized my code into packages, including "DAO," which contains two classes: "interfaceDAO" and "animalDAO." The latter class implements the methods defined in the "interfaceDAO."

Inside the "animalDAO," I've implemented several functions to manage animal data, including:

Select All: Retrieve all animal records.
Select by ID: Fetch a specific animal by its ID.
Insert: Add new animal records.
Update: Modify existing animal records.
Delete: Remove animal records from the database.
To facilitate database connectivity, I've created a "hibernate.cfg.xml" configuration file. Additionally, I've developed a "hibernateUtil.java" class to create a "SessionFactory," a critical component for managing Hibernate sessions.

Finally, I've created a main test class, "testAnimal.java," within the "test" package. This class allows me to execute the functions I've defined in the "animalDAO" class. Despite successfully connecting to the database and displaying the menu, an error message persists.`

```
animalDAO class

package DAO;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import model.animal;
import util.hibernateUtil;

public class animalDAO implements interfaceDAO<animal> {

    @Override
    public List<animal> sellectAll() {
        List<animal> list = new ArrayList();
        try {
            SessionFactory sf = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
            if (sf != null) {
                // open & begin transaction
                Session s = sf.openSession();
                Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
                
                // transaction
                String hql = "from animal";
                Query q = s.createQuery(hql);
                list = q.getResultList();
                
                // comit & close transaction
                trans.commit();
                sf.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public animal selectByID(animal t) {
        List<animal> list = new ArrayList<>();
        
        try {
            SessionFactory sf = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
            if (sf != null) {
                Session s = sf.openSession();
                Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
                
                String hql = "from animal a where a.id=:id";
                Query q = s.createQuery(hql);
                q.setParameter("id", t.getId());
                list = q.getResultList();
                
                trans.commit();
                sf.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            return list.get(0);
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean insert(animal t) {
        boolean result = false;
        
        try {
            SessionFactory sf = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
            if (sf != null) {
                Session s = sf.openSession();
                Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
                
                // save: chỉ lưu khi chưa tồn tại
//              s.save(t);
                
                //saveOrUpdate: thêm mới khi chưa tồn tại, cập nhật dữ liệu khi đã tồn tại
                s.saveOrUpdate(t);
                
                trans.commit();
                sf.close();
                
                return true;
            }
            
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(animal t) {
        boolean result = false;
        
        try {
            SessionFactory sf = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
            if (sf != null) {
                Session s = sf.openSession();
                Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
                
                // save: chỉ lưu khi chưa tồn tại
//              s.save(t);
                
                //saveOrUpdate: thêm mới khi chưa tồn tại, cập nhật dữ liệu khi đã tồn tại
                s.saveOrUpdate(t);
                
                trans.commit();
                sf.close();
                
                return true;
            }
            
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(animal t) {
        try (SessionFactory sf = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()) {
            if (sf != null) {
                try(Session s = sf.openSession()){
                    
                    Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
                    
                    s.delete(t);
                    
                    trans.commit();
                    sf.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

```
hibernateUtil.java

package util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class hibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    
    public static void shutdown() {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

```
hibernate.cfg.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=animal;encrypt=false;</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123456789Thien_Phu</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        
        <mapping class="model.animal"/>
        
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

```
testAnimal.java class

package test;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import DAO.animalDAO;
import model.animal;
import util.hibernateUtil;

public class testAnimal {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        SessionFactory sf = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        int choice = 0;
        
        do {
            System.out.println("============================== \r\n"
                    + "1. Select All \r\n"
                    + "2. Select by id \r\n"
                    + "3. Insert \r\n"
                    + "4. Update \r\n"
                    + "5. Delete \r\n");
            choice = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            
            switch (choice) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("exit!");
                break;
                
            case 1:
                
                if (sf != null) {
                    Session s = sf.openSession();
                    Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
                    
                    animalDAO ad = new animalDAO();
                    List<animal> list = ad.sellectAll();
                    for (animal a : list) {
                        System.out.println(a);
                    }
                    
                    trans.commit();
                    sf.close();
                }
                break;
                
            case 2:
                
                if (sf != null) {
                    Session s = sf.openSession();
                    Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
                    
                    animalDAO ad = new animalDAO();
                    System.out.println("Enter ID: ");
                    int id = sc.nextInt();
                    
                    animal a = new animal();
                    a.setId(id);
                    animal result = ad.selectByID(a);   
                    System.out.println(result);
                    
                    trans.commit();
                    sf.close();
                }
                break;
                
            case 3:
                if (sf != null) {
                    Session s = sf.openSession();
                    Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
                    
                    animalDAO ad = new animalDAO();
                    System.out.println("Enter animal name: ");
                    String name = sc.nextLine();
                    
                    System.out.println("Enter animal date of birth [yyyy MM dd]: ");
                    int year = sc.nextInt();
                    int month = sc.nextInt();
                    int day = sc.nextInt();
                    sc.nextLine();
                    
                    Date dob = new Date(year - 1900, month - 1, day);

                    System.out.println("Enter sex/gender [true / false]: ");
                    boolean sex = sc.nextBoolean();
                    
                    animal a1 = new animal(name, dob, sex);
                    ad.insert(a1);
                    
                    trans.commit();
                    sf.close();
                }
                break;
                
            case 4:
                if (sf != null) {
                    Session s = sf.openSession();
                    Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
                    
                    animalDAO ad = new animalDAO();
                    System.out.println("enter new name for animal: ");
                    String name = sc.nextLine();
                    
                    System.out.println("Enter new date of birth for animal [xxxx xx xx]: ");
                    int year = sc.nextInt();
                    int month = sc.nextInt();
                    int day = sc.nextInt();
                    sc.nextLine();
                    Date dob = new Date(year - 1900, month - 1, day);
                    
                    System.out.println("enter new sex/gender [true / false]: ");
                    boolean sex = sc.nextBoolean();
                    
                    System.out.println("Enter ID: ");
                    int id = sc.nextInt();
                    
                    animal a2 = new animal(name, dob, sex);
                    a2.setId(id);
                    ad.update(a2);
                    
                    trans.commit();
                    sf.close();
                }
                
                
                break;
                
            case 5:
                if (sf != null) {
                    Session s = sf.openSession();
                    Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
                    
                    animalDAO ad = new animalDAO();
                    System.out.println("Enter ID: ");
                    int id = sc.nextInt();
                    
                    animal a3 = new animal(id);
                    a3.setId(id);
                    ad.delete(a3);
                    
                    trans.commit();
                    sf.close();
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        } while (choice != 0);
    }
}
```

```
Error log

Sep 06, 2023 9:04:46 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.15.Final
Sep 06, 2023 9:04:46 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
Sep 06, 2023 9:04:47 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Sep 06, 2023 9:04:47 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] at URL [jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=animal;encrypt=false;]
Sep 06, 2023 9:04:47 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=sa}
Sep 06, 2023 9:04:47 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Sep 06, 2023 9:04:47 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Sep 06, 2023 9:04:47 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
Sep 06, 2023 9:04:47 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@3b8ec001] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Sep 06, 2023 9:04:48 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
============================== 
1. Select All 
2. Select by id 
3. Insert 
4. Update 
5. Delete 

1
Hibernate: select animal0_.id as id1_0_, animal0_.dateOfBirth as dateofbi2_0_, animal0_.name as name3_0_, animal0_.sex as sex4_0_ from animal animal0_
Sep 06, 2023 9:04:50 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PoolState stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=animal;encrypt=false;]
Sep 06, 2023 9:04:50 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections close
ERROR: Connection leak detected: there are 1 unclosed connections upon shutting down pool jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=animal;encrypt=false;
Sep 06, 2023 9:04:50 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl validateConnectionsReturned
ERROR: Connection leak detected: there are 1 unclosed connections!
animal [id=1, name=cat, dateOfBirth=null, sex=false]
animal [id=2, name=fish, dateOfBirth=2003-04-05, sex=true]
animal [id=6, name=carrovet, dateOfBirth=2003-12-02, sex=false]
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at test.testAnimal.main(testAnimal.java:49)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:231)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:1728)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.commit(SQLServerConnection.java:4451)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.commit(SQLServerConnection.java:4432)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:86)
    ... 3 more
```

`in the error log it said Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection I try may way check all the jdbc connection but still not work`

I try t change some main thing in the test class,
I create a SessionFactory outside the loop do while
then invery case I open a new session and begin a new transaction
commit and close in that case also

```
case 1:
                
                if (sf != null) {
                    Session s = sf.openSession();
                    Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
                    
                    animalDAO ad = new animalDAO();
                    List<animal> list = ad.sellectAll();
                    for (animal a : list) {
                        System.out.println(a);
                    }
                    
                    trans.commit();
                    sf.close();
                }
                break;
                
            case 2:
                
                if (sf != null) {
                    Session s = sf.openSession();
                    Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
                    
                    animalDAO ad = new animalDAO();
                    System.out.println("Enter ID: ");
                    int id = sc.nextInt();
                    
                    animal a = new animal();
                    a.setId(id);
                    animal result = ad.selectByID(a);   
                    System.out.println(result);
                    
                    trans.commit();
                    sf.close();
                }
                break;
                
            case 3:
                if (sf != null) {
                    Session s = sf.openSession();
                    Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
                    
                    animalDAO ad = new animalDAO();
                    System.out.println("Enter animal name: ");
                    String name = sc.nextLine();
                    
                    System.out.println("Enter animal date of birth [yyyy MM dd]: ");
                    int year = sc.nextInt();
                    int month = sc.nextInt();
                    int day = sc.nextInt();
                    sc.nextLine();
                    
                    Date dob = new Date(year - 1900, month - 1, day);

                    System.out.println("Enter sex/gender [true / false]: ");
                    boolean sex = sc.nextBoolean();
                    
                    animal a1 = new animal(name, dob, sex);
                    ad.insert(a1);
                    
                    trans.commit();
                    sf.close();
                }
                break;
```

but seem it it wont work as this way

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I have already figured out where the error is.

So the error based on the `animalDAO` class.
In the methods `selectAll`, `selectByID`, `insert`, `update` and `delete`, I forgot to surround with `try...catch`. The very important step so as to check if the methods got an error or not.
So after I surrounded all the methods in `try...catch`, the project can work properly.

Here is an update of `animalDAO` class:

```
package DAO;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import model.animal;
import util.hibernateUtil;

public class animalDAO implements interfaceDAO<animal> {

// this is previous method code
//  @Override
//  public List<animal> sellectAll() {
//      List<animal> list = new ArrayList();
//      try {
//          SessionFactory sf = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
//          if (sf != null) {
//              // open & begin transaction
//              Session s = sf.openSession();
//              Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
//              
//              // transaction
//              String hql = "from animal";
//              Query q = s.createQuery(hql);
//              list = q.getResultList();
//              
//              // commit & close transaction
//              trans.commit();
//              sf.close();
//          }
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
//      return list;
//  }
//
//  @Override
//  public animal selectByID(animal t) {
//      List<animal> list = new ArrayList<>();
//      
//      try {
//          SessionFactory sf = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
//          if (sf != null) {
//              Session s = sf.openSession();
//              Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
//              
//              String hql = "from animal a where a.id=:id";
//              Query q = s.createQuery(hql);
//              q.setParameter("id", t.getId());
//              list = q.getResultList();
//              
//              trans.commit();
//              sf.close();
//          }
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
//      
//      if (list.size() > 0) {
//          return list.get(0);
//      }else {
//          return null;
//      }
//  }
//
//
//  @Override
//  public boolean insert(animal t) {
//      boolean result = false;
//      
//      try {
//          SessionFactory sf = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
//          if (sf != null) {
//              Session s = sf.openSession();
//              Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
//              
//              // save: chỉ lưu khi chưa tồn tại
////                s.save(t);
//              
//              //saveOrUpdate: thêm mới khi chưa tồn tại, cập nhật dữ liệu khi đã tồn tại
//              s.saveOrUpdate(t);
//              
//              trans.commit();
//              sf.close();
//              
//              return true;
//          }
//          
//          
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
//      return false;
//  }
//
//  @Override
//  public boolean update(animal t) {
//      boolean result = false;
//      
//      try {
//          SessionFactory sf = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
//          if (sf != null) {
//              Session s = sf.openSession();
//              Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
//              
//              // save: chỉ lưu khi chưa tồn tại
////                s.save(t);
//              
//              //saveOrUpdate: thêm mới khi chưa tồn tại, cập nhật dữ liệu khi đã tồn tại
//              s.saveOrUpdate(t);
//              
//              trans.commit();
//              sf.close();
//              
//              return true;
//          }
//          
//          
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
//      return false;
//  }
//
//  @Override
//  public boolean delete(animal t) {
//      try (SessionFactory sf = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()) {
//          if (sf != null) {
//              try(Session s = sf.openSession()){
//                  
//                  Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
//                  
//                  s.delete(t);
//                  
//                  trans.commit();
//                  sf.close();
//              }
//          }
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//          return false;
//      }
//      return true;
//  }
    

// this is new code after update
    @Override
    public List<animal> sellectAll() {
        List<animal> list = new ArrayList();
        SessionFactory sf = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        if (sf != null) {
            try(Session s = sf.openSession();) {
                Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
                
                // transaction
                String hql = "from animal";
                Query q = s.createQuery(hql);
                list = q.getResultList();
                trans.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                sf.close();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public animal selectByID(animal t) {
        List<animal> list = new ArrayList<>();
        SessionFactory sf = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        if (sf != null) {
            try(Session s = sf.openSession();) {
                Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
                
                String hql = "from animal a where a.id=:id";
                Query q = s.createQuery(hql);
                q.setParameter("id", t.getId());
                list = q.getResultList();
                
                trans.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                sf.close();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            return list.get(0);
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean insert(animal t) {
        boolean result = false;
        SessionFactory sf = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        if (sf != null) {
            try(Session s = sf.openSession();) {
                Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
                s.saveOrUpdate(t);
                
                trans.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                sf.close();
                e.printStackTrace();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(animal t) {
        boolean result = false;
        SessionFactory sf = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        if (sf != null) {
            try(Session s = sf.openSession();) {
                Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
                s.saveOrUpdate(t);
                
                trans.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                sf.close();
                e.printStackTrace();
                return true;
            }
            
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(animal t) {
        try (SessionFactory sf = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()) {
            if (sf != null) {
                try(Session s = sf.openSession()){
                    
                    Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
                    
                    s.delete(t);
                    
                    trans.commit();
                    sf.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

So the error has been fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Surrounding `Session` in try catch block automatically closes it after transaction is complete without requiring you to close it manually